# Drop element at the cursor location of a background table but, the middle of element's cell is detact, need top cell of the element will show

Tags: jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have some long draggable elements that I can drop in all cells of a background table. When I start dragging this kind of element hover my droppable containers (the cells of my table), the middle of  element's cell is detact, but I need top cell of the element will detact. [image]

I need top cell of the element will detact.[image]